# c++ compiling error when using member functions as a template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to pass a member function pointer as a template parameter. Here is the code:

```
template <typename Ret, typename T, Ret(T::*mptr)()>
Handle<Value> get_value (Local<String> name, const AccessorInfo& info)
{
    ...
}

template <typename Ret, typename T>
void mbind (const char* name, Ret (T::*mptr)())
{
    ....
    objectTemplate->SetAccessor (String::NewSymbol (name),get_value<Ret,T,mptr>);
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
wrapper.h:184:5: error: ‘mptr’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int (Cell::*)()’
wrapper.h:184:5: error: it must be a pointer-to-member of the form `&X::Y'
...
```

As far as I know pointers to member functions are valid template parameters. I don't understand what's wrong with the previous code. The compiler I'm using is g++ 4.5.2 under Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

It's seems the code should be wrong as `mptr` is a runtime variable. On the other hand, the previous excerpt of code compiles:

http://ideone.com/cv8pq

so...is it correct? does it depend on the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mptr` is a runtime variable - you cannot give it as a template parameter. Check http://ideone.com/CIL4C .

**Edit**

Strange thing is http://ideone.com/cv8pq where something similar to your code successfully  compiles and works.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the pointer to the member function as a template parameter of `mbind ()` and it works. The invocation is like this: `mbind<int,Cell,&Cell::getWidth> ("getWidth");`
Now I'm wondering if there is any other way to make the invocation to `mbind()` simpler for the user (without having to specify all these template arguments).
Thanks!

Comment: so...we don't know whether it is valid (and only supported by some compilers) or not :d

Answer (score 1):

`mbind` should already take a template argument:

```
template <typename Ret, typename T, Ret (T::*mptr)()> 
void mbind (const char* name) {
    objectTemplate->SetAccessor (String::NewSymbol (name),get_value<Ret,T,mptr>()); 
}
```

PS: you forgot the `()` after `get_value<>`.